# "Bring up a topic" or "bring up a subject"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

If I start speaking about something, do I "bring up the **topic** of [sth.]" or "bring up the **subject** of [sth.]"?

Comment: What is the doubt here? Either will do, because they are synonymous.

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary?

Comment: Anonym: thanks for your "helpful" comment. While this is "English language & usage" website I think I can ask native-speakers which version would they prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use either one.  I usually

> bring up a topic

and

> change the subject

But this is just habit.